# Why using cookie to login a website failed in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, cookies, scrapy

I want to use cookie that i have got to access a website and get some information only can be seen after user login, but when me try it, the result shows the user isn't login the website, this is my code, someone can tell me how to fix the problem?

```
   LOGIN_URL ="https://www.yaozh.com/login/"
   values = {'username': 'username', 'pwd': 'password'} # , 'submit' : 'Login'
   postdata = urllib.parse.urlencode(values).encode()
   user_agent = r'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36'
   headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent, 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

   cookie_filename = 'cookie.txt'
   cookie = http.cookiejar.MozillaCookieJar(cookie_filename)
   handler = urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie)
   opener = urllib.request.build_opener(handler)
   request = urllib.request.Request(LOGIN_URL, postdata, headers)

   try:
    response = opener.open(request)
    page = response.read().decode()
  # print(page)
   except urllib.error.URLError as e:
   print(e.code, ':', e.reason)
   cookie.save(ignore_discard=True, ignore_expires=True)  
   print(cookie)
   for item in cookie:
   print('Name = ' + item.name)
   print('Value = ' + item.value)

   get_url = 'https://db.yaozh.com/instruct?p=1&pageSize=20'  
   get_request = urllib.request.Request(get_url, headers=headers)
   get_response = opener.open(get_request)
   print(get_response.read())
   bs=BeautifulSoup(get_response,"html.parser")
   urls=bs.find_all(name='a',attrs={"href":re.compile("\.doc")},recursive=True)
   print(len(urls))
   for url in urls:
     print(url["href"])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved, if you face same problem, i guess you should chcek the information post to server is all? Many websites need some imformation that true users can't see to judge the requester is true user. Good luck for you!